# Socket listening without binding C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcplistener

I am trying to make a c# socket application which involves listening to a certain port and take any message sent to this port. 
The problem is, I want to make it in a non-binding way. I mean, when I use TCPListener and accept socket,once a connection came, a socket for this connection returns and it deal ONLY with this connection.

What I want is different, I want any connection ( from any remote socket ) to send and I get their messages without being tied with any of them

What I am doing is 2 background workers, one for sending and other for receiving (i.e they are on different ports ). the app will send through the sending some commands depends on the pre-defined message format got on the receiving.
I hope it was clear enough

Comment: if you dont need the guarantees and other features of tcp you could use udp, but depends on the usecase. Tcp is by implementation a connection-ful protocol. You should probably ask yourself why you want this, and if there is no common server-client setup  that could solve your problem.

Comment: I still need TCP for other reasons not related to this point.

Comment: A listening tcp socket can accept many clients and have a connection to each, spawning one socket for every connecting client. Then you could have a class that aggregates all the messages from the sockets to one place. Im not sure what you are after

Comment: What I am after is something like this:
listener.receive(buffer) and get any message got on the port I am listening on without being dedicated to a certain client.

Comment: But the "client" here conceptually represents a connection to a specific client, right? Why not keep your clients (they'll be easier to clean up if you keep hold of them), and just aggregate their messages with a controlling entity that the clients all post messages to?

Comment: @spender Sorry, Can you explain your idea in details ?